# Подключение сервера tomcat в eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Добрый день!

Tomcat запущен, `http://localhost:8080/` открывается. Пытаюсь добавить Tomcat в eclipse, но его нет в списке server runtime environment. Ищу в меню Windows -> preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments, там ничего нет. В том же окне жму Add, указываю папку с Tomcat и результата ноль. Если нажать Download additional server adapters - то его с в списке нет.
Подскажите что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решилась перестановкой eclipse, надо ставить eclipse ide **ee** а у меня была eclipse ide mars

Answer (score 1):

После нажатия `Add`:

- Открылось окошко, где необходимо выбрать `runtime environment` -> выбирай в зависимости от того, какая версия tomcat установлена -> жми `Next`
- Укажи название нового сервера, путь в папку с установленным tomcat и JRE, установленный в Eclipse
- Жми `Finish` -> в `Server Runtime Environments` должен появиться сконфигурированный сервер